# Intellij can't find JDK/SDK

Tags: java, jre, intellij, sdk

Here are my environment variables for Java:

```
$ echo JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
$ echo $JRE_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
```

When I click **Create new project** with `IntelliJ`, it says `<NO_SDK>` and it gives me a link to download JDK.

Here is a screen shot of the error:
[image: IntelliJ error]

I am using Linux for the first time, can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Glad you fixed it! Can you accept your answer by clicking the check to the left to let other people know it is correct?

Comment: can't accept it till 2 days

Comment: That doesn't actually solve the issue if you do not want to use the Oracle JDK. The original question is asking about using OpenJDK.